# Passing paramater as attribute not working XSL PDF from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

So I am trying to pass background color as parameter to the table-cell for an PDF XSLT.

```
  <xsl:template name="colorCell">
     <xsl:param name="bgColor"/>
        <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" background-color="$bgColor">
                  ....
     </fo:table-cell>
   </xsl:template>
```

But somehow it ends up as being set to background-color="$bgColor"> instead of background-color="red">

This is how I am calling the template:

```
  <xsl:call-template name="colorCell">
     <xsl:with-param name="bgColor" select="'white'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

This is the error:

```
SEVERE: Invalid property value encountered in background-color="$bgColor"
```

Am I doing it wrong? Any ideas? 
Last note I am using FOP for generating pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a variable you need to place it in an *attribute value template*:

```
<fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" background-color="{$bgColor}">
```

See: [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

Comment: thanks.. I thought I have tried that and it did not work but this morning it did... oh well I was probably running off of an old xsl or something when I tried it